# AngularJS $http.get does not return expected data from API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, api, get

I am attempting to create a mobile phone application with a javascript / AngularJS frontend that communicats with a node js / express js backend.

I believe that I have properly enabled cors but am not completely certain that it has been done in the correct manner. None of the frontend files are hosted on a server (not even a local one).  The node js server is hosted online as well as a mongo db server that it interacts with.

So far I am able to make POST's to my API that create a new user and reflect this in the database.  I also have a login that POST's to an authentication function which returns a JSON Web Token (JWT).  From here I should be able to put the JWT in the header of requests with the key "Authorization" to get access to the other parts of the API (eg: GET /currentUser).

Attempting to GET /currentUser when the JWT is in the header with postman returns all of the expected data.  When I attempt to perform the same GET from my frontend (with JWT in header), I get the following OPTIONS response via firebug: "Reload the page to get source for: MyHostedApi/api/users"

I'm wondering if this is some kind of cors issue, incorrectly set authorization header, bad formatting of the $http.get, etc.  Any help is greatly appreciated!  I'd be glad to provide any parts of the source that are relevant.

This is what my GET looks like:

```
$http.get("MyHostedApi/api/users/currentUser")
            .success(function(response) {
                $scope.userData = response.data.firstName;
            });
```

Comment: Could you replace `.success` with `.then` and try it again ?

Comment: The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead.

Comment: replacing with .then gives the same result.  What I have described is the shortcut usage from : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http , I recall attempting to use the general usage and receiving a status 0 with none of the expected data.  Not sure if that's relevant.